# Put AsyncHTTPClient or other awaitable in Tornado's get method wiil create ThreadPoolExcutor automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

How can I prevent a Tornado server from creating ThreadPoolExector automatically.

env:

windows 10

python 3.7

Tornado 6.0.2

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest, AsyncHTTPClient

class TestHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    WRITE_MP3_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096

    async def get(self):
        try:
            http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
            req = HTTPRequest(
                url='https://www.google.com',
                method='GET')
            response = await http_client.fetch(req)
            contents = response.body.decode('utf-8')
            self.write(contents)
        except Exception as e:
            self.write(str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        tornado.web.url(r"/", TestHandler),
        ])
    app.listen(5000)
    print("Service Started")
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

I debug this code in VS Code and query from http://127.0.0.1:5000 by Chrome, When I set up breakpoints in Vs Code at debugging, I found that a ThreadPoolExectutor emerged at call stack every query, will it increase unlimitedly and shutdown?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ThreadPoolExecutor is used for DNS requests, and comes from the standard library's `asyncio` module. It has a limited size, so it will stop growing at some point (the limit depends on your version of python). You can control this with `asyncio`'s `set_default_executor` method, but I wouldn't worry about it.